# ExecutionService. how get results after all threads finished?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have list of requests, and i need to send them in threads and collect all responses when threads are finished. How can i know that all treads are finished?

```
List<Task<Response>> tasks = new ArrayList<Task<Response>>();
for (Request request : requestList) {
        tasks.add(executor.runTask(new RequestCaller(request))); // runTask is my method witch will run threads   
}
for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size; i++) {
   result.add(tasks.get(i).get); // here i want to collect results, but i need to run this loop only when all threads will finish
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [java.util.concurrent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package.

One option is to use an [`ExecutorCompletionService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html). This class arranges that submitted tasks are, upon completion, placed on a queue accessible using [`take()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html#take%28%29).

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use a [CountDownLatch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), pass the latch object to each Thread, have each thread call `countDown()` on their latch object when complete, and then wait on the threads by calling `await()` on the latch wherever you want to pause until all threads are complete.

```
// note: code not tested
List<Task<Response>> tasks = new ArrayList<Task<Response>>();
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(tasks.size());
for (Request request : requestList) {
   // pass latch into RequestCaller
   tasks.add(executor.runTask(new RequestCaller(request, latch))); // runTask is my method which will run threads   
}
// in RequestCaller, call countDown() on the latch when finished.

latch.await(); // wait for all threads to call countDown() on their latches.
for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
   result.add(tasks.get(i).get); // here i want to collect results, but i need to run this loop only when all threads will finish
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [ExecutorService.invokeAll](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29), which takes a list of callables, executes them in parallel, and returns when they have all completed (or optionally after a timeout)